# How to use regex function to remove all html tags including what's inside in it like class name, etc?

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have a text file with

```
<p class="className" style="background-color:black">Hello World</p>
```

it should give me an output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: [The pony, he comes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do next:

```
import re
text = '<p class="className" style="background-color:black">Hello World</p>' 
print(re.findall(r'\<.+\>(.+)\<\/.+\>', text)) # ['Hello World']
```

Example with a table:

Let's assume that you have such table:

```
table = '''
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Head 1</th>
          <th>Head 2</th>
          <th>Head 3</th>
          <th>Head 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data 1</td>
          <td>data 2</td>
          <td>data 3</td>
          <td>data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
'''
```

You can do next to get all data from td tags:

```
print(re.findall(r'\<td.*\>(.+)\<\/.+\>', table)) # ['data 1', 'data 2', 'data 3', 'data 4']
```

I hope it's clear, or you can use different libs that provide api for working with html like BeatufulSoup, lxml

Comment: this doesnt remove the table tags like tr and td etc

Comment: @MakInsane, read about pony *(link in comments under question)*. Try to avoid using regular expressions for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [XML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = '<p class="className" style="background-color:black">Hello World</p>'
root = ET.fromstring(s)
output = root.text
```